# How to make a Bash function for killing processes accessing a port

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to simplify killing all processes on a given port.  How could I do this within my .bashrc file using the following command?

```
 $ lsof -i tcp:3000 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

hopefully I could simplify this to something like

```
 killport 3000
```

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Use a [function](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

> killport() { lsof -i tcp:$1 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill ; }

Answer (score 0):

For mac m1 users add this to your bash/zshrc file

```
function findandkill(){
 lsof -t -i tcp:$1 | xargs kill
} 

alias killport=findandkill
```

now you just need to type in your terminal something like `killport 3000`